# Calculate the average of Lists int C# Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing n pair key/value and I want to get the total average of the **first two** values in each list in my dictionary. 
Here is an example:

```
    private Dictionary<int, List<float>> _myValues = new Dictionary<int, List<float>>
    {
        {1, new List<float>{0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f},
        {2, new List<float>{0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f, 0.7f},
        {3, new List<float>{0.8f}
    };
```

For this example, I want the average of these values (`0.1f`, `0.2f`, `0.4f`, `0.5f`, `0.8f`).

I see that I can do this using for/foreach loop, but I wonder if it's possible to get that average using a simple LINQ query.

Comment: You will get no benefit from using a dictionary this way. It will be the same speed as searching and outputting items from a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For this example, I want the average of these values (0.1f, 0.2f,
>   0.4f, 0.5f, 0.8f).

```
Dictionary<int, List<float>> _myValues = new Dictionary<int, List<float>>
{
    {1, new List<float>{0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f}},
    {2, new List<float>{0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f, 0.7f}},
    {3, new List<float>{0.8f}}
};

var result = _myValues.Values.SelectMany(z => z.Take(2)).Average();
```

`Values` will get the values from the `Dictionary` (i.e. ignore the `Keys` since they don't impact the result). `Take(2)` will get the first two entries from each list. `SelectMany` will effectively concatenate all of those two entries into a single projection. And `Average` will average them.